# failed to export Project Plu-gin

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin

I'm creating an eclipse Plug-in Project that works fine when runing from the development enviroment, but when we export it and put it in another eclipse, it doesn't works at all.

Trying to see the problem, we've detected that is stoping when loading the our class which extends the other classes which extends the class wsdlInterfaceConfig, WSDLLocator , and any trace we put inside the class (using the System.err) doesn't appear in the eclipse log.

We've included all the library dependencies in the plugin to avoid this kind of problem.

Can anyone give me some clue about it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you turned on the Error Log? I had a similar problem a few weeks ago, and it turned out that it was a "unresolved compilation problem" stemming from the dumb ant tool, that used wrong java encoding.

Comment: On top of the error log, what do you mean "included all the library dependencies"?  That you've listed them all in Require-Bundle?  Are they already in your runtime platform?  Or do you mean dependencies that are 3rd party jars?

Comment: Hi,

The Error Log is turned on since it writes some traces in the workspace log that I have put with System.err.println().

Exactly, the dependencies are 3rd party jars and they are included in my runtime platform.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to solve the problem.

When exporting a plugin that contains another jar, you must export it clearing the "Package plug-ins as individual JAR archives" check in the Export tab.

When we do it that way, we export a folder and not a .jar so it works fine since plugins doesn't seem to support jars inside them.

Hope it helps!